# Beautiful Soup import Part of table

Tags: python, import, beautifulsoup

im trying to import a specific Part of a Table with Beautiful Soup.

The Website: https://sky.lea.moe/api/Lulonautdumpling/Raspberry/skills?html&progress

I only want to import the number under "Alchemy", in this Case 30. I only found a way to import the whole Table but not a specific Part. Something else as Beautiful Soup is also fine, as long as it works.

The HTML Code of the site is:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Taming</td>
         <td>26</td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td>4492501.365976427</td>
         <td>670076</td>
         <td>900000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Farming</td>
         <td>23</td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td>2309614.4305900014</td>
         <td>587189</td>
         <td>600000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Mining</td>
         <td>21</td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td>1124768.2399988933</td>
         <td>302343</td>
         <td>400000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Combat</td>
         <td>21</td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td>1162005.9407998077</td>
         <td>339580</td>
         <td>400000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Foraging</td>
         <td>34</td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td>14681966.569883931</td>
         <td>859541</td>
         <td>1700000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Fishing</td>
         <td>18</td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td>259926.63599998475</td>
         <td>37501</td>
         <td>100000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Enchanting</td>
         <td>13</td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td>46890.39004738184</td>
         <td>14465</td>
         <td>15000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Alchemy</td>
         <td>30</td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td>8277261.6399999745</td>
         <td>254836</td>
         <td>1300000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Carpentry</td>
         <td>19</td>
         <td>50</td>
         <td>388259.2533598877</td>
         <td>65834</td>
         <td>200000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Runecrafting</td>
         <td>18</td>
         <td>25</td>
         <td>19332.282000000003</td>
         <td>382</td>
         <td>5000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Wolf</td>
         <td>4</td>
         <td>9</td>
         <td>1540</td>
         <td>1540</td>
         <td>5000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Spider</td>
         <td>4</td>
         <td>9</td>
         <td>1005</td>
         <td>1005</td>
         <td>5000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Zombie</td>
         <td>5</td>
         <td>9</td>
         <td>5325</td>
         <td>5325</td>
         <td>20000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Fairy Souls</td>
         <td>191</td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(<HTML text>)

table_body = soup.find('tbody')
for row in table_body.find_all('tr'):
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    if cols[0].text.strip() == 'Alchemy':
        retval = cols[1].text
        break

print(retval)
```

Comment: Thanks i cant upvote your answer but Thanks for taking your time!